# Unable to show uploaded files using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, file-upload

I have followed Miguel Grinberg's [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) and also his [tutorial on uploading files](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-file-uploads-with-flask) using Flask. I'm trying to combine the two to build my own web app. I have a site that handles user logins and allows files (scans of exam papers) to be uploaded to app/uploads/userID. The file details, including the filename, are stored (successfully) in a SQLite database. I can see the files in File Explorer and VS Code, but I cannot get them to display / download from within the website. I don't want to use the static folder as I want to keep each user's uploads private to them.

Here is the relevant section of routes.py:

```py
@app.route('/user/<username>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def user(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404()
    papers=user.papers.all()
    form = PaperForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        uploaded_file = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)
        if filename != '':
            file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
            if file_ext not in app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS']:
                flash('Invalid file type. Only PDF files are accepted.')
                abort(400)
        myPath = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'],current_user.get_id())
        if os.path.isdir(myPath)==False:
            os.mkdir(myPath)
        uploaded_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'],current_user.get_id(), filename))
        paper = Paper(paper_name=form.paper.data, author=current_user, filename = filename)
        db.session.add(paper)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your paper has been added to the database.')
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=user.username)) 

    return render_template('user.html', user=user, form=form, papers=papers)


@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
@login_required
def upload(filename):
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], current_user.get_id()), filename)
```

And here is the template for user.html, which shows the upload form and beneath it displays a table of all the papers uploaded by that user:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block app_content %}

<h2>Add a paper</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<h2>My Papers</h2>
<table class="table">
    {% for paper in papers %}
    <tr valign="top">
        <td>{{ paper.paper_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ paper.author.username }}</td>
        <td>{{ paper.created_time }}</td>
        <td>{{ url_for('upload', filename=paper.filename) }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ url_for('upload', filename=paper.filename) }}">{{ paper.filename }}</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

When clicking on the link to a file I just get a 404 file not found error.

Update:

I found a partial solution elsewhere on Stack Overflow. I'm pretty sure the problem is the path to the files. If I change the upload path to
`UPLOAD_PATH = './uploads/'` then I can see the files which have been uploaded already. However, when I then try to upload a file it fails with an error that the new directory couldn't be created. If I create a directory parallel to the app folder rather than within it I can upload, but of course downloads then fail! I am using Windows, which I suspect may be part of the problem.

```
Examscanner/
├─ app/
│  ├─ static/
│  ├─ __pycache__/
│  ├─ templates/
│  ├─ uploads/
│  ├─ __init__
│  ├─ errors.py
│  ├─ forms.py
│  ├─ models.py
│  ├─ routes.py
├─ migrations/
├─ examvenv/
```

Comment: What's the url when you received 404 ?

Comment: Thanks for responding. It's: http://127.0.0.1:5000/uploads/e.pdf where e.pdf is the filename. The directory for the file is uploads/3/e.pdf but I thought the upload function would handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working in the end by changing the config.py file to include:

```py
    APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    UPLOAD_PATH = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'uploads')
```

The files are stored in the uploads folder alongside the app folder rather than within it. I'm hoping this won't cause other problems further down the line.